How to calculate the impedance accurately?
I connected a circuit as shown in the following figure. The device under test (DUT) is powered by a battery. The negtive pole of the battery is connected with the conducting housing of the DUT, while the positive is connected with the terminal of the DUT. And the conducting housing of the DUT is connected with the ground.
If I divide the measured voltage by current, is the result the impedance of the DUT?


Nope, you are measuring resistance.

You don't really get an impedance.
You have a constant DC voltage at DUT and the DUT takes some amount of current.
All you can do is to use the current and voltage measurement to come up with a value of equivalent resistance, so that if you replace the DUT with that resistance, you should get identical current and voltage as with the DUT.
However, if the DUT is not a resistor, the value of equivalent resistor is useless. If the DUT is a device which takes constant power regardless of voltage, it will have a different resistance at different voltages and the current does not follow Ohm's law.
And with impedance you generally mean not only resistance at DC, but if the load has reactive elements, the impedance is a value of resistive and reactive components at some AC frequency.

Dividing the measured voltage by the measured current in your drawn circuit is the impedance of DUT in a very limited case. We must assume all of the following things:

DUT obeys Ohm's Law i.e. the voltage and the current have a certain ratio. That's a severe limitation. For example semiconductor parts do not obey Ohm's Law. If DUT contains capacitors, inductors, semiconductors, motors or batteries or nearly anything else than resistors the answer would be NO in your DC circuit.

You limit the case only to measurements at DC. In that case the result is also called DC resistance. AC impedance is much more complex thing

You are not - maybe unconsciously - cooking together a soup which mixes the impedance concept of a two terminal circuit element to other concepts which are also called impedances.


For example transmission lines have impedance. You can go and buy for example a piece of 50 Ohm coaxial cable, but that 50 Ohm cannot be measured in your DC circuit. Multiport circuits have port to port interconnection impedances, etc...
Materials have impedances as well for mechanical and electromagnetic waves. For example, when we talk about the relation between electric and magnetic components of a radiowave, you are very likely breathing 377 Ohm air.
